# laravel group by query : Syntax error or access violation: 1055

Tags: laravel

I am writing query in laravel 5.7 which gives following error

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'demoecommerce.orders.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `table_users`.`name`, `orders`.*, `orders_details`.`orders_id` from `orders_details` inner join `orders` on `orders`.`id` = `orders_details`.`orders_id` inner join `products` on `orders_details`.`product_id` = `products`.`product_id` inner join `table_users` on `table_users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id` group by `orders_id`)

In mysql it run correctly.

```
 $orders = DB::table('orders_details')
                    ->join('orders','orders.id','=','orders_details.orders_id')
                    ->join('products','orders_details.product_id','=','products.product_id')
                    ->join('table_users','table_users.id','=','orders.user_id')
                    ->select('table_users.name','orders.*','orders_details.orders_id')
                    ->groupBy('orders_id')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: Seems like this is a MySQL issue that can be resolved changing Laravel config as `strict => true` to `strict => false` in `config/database.php`

Answer (score 2):

step 1. go to the config folder and open database file and change *... 'strict' => true`*, to *false*.
step 2. go to Providers folder  and open Appserviceprovoder file and do it

A. `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`

B. inside `public function boot(): void` function write below line

```
  DB::statement("SET SQL_MODE= ''");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you have groupBy in your SQL query, you can only select columns that are part of groupby in SQL else you must have some aggregation(sum, count, average..) on the columns

You can add some more details, about what you need from this query, order count? or order details per user.

Also, you can try looking at GroupBy on collection. [Laravel documentation GroupBy on Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby)